# Can I perform a rolling upgrade with the Rancher HA Setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, rancher

I have a Rancher HA Setup with 3 instances and an external DB (RDS mariadb) and want to perform an upgrade with as little downtime as possible. The [rancher documentation](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.2/en/upgrading/#multi-nodes) only states that

> When upgrading a HA setup, the Rancher server setup will be down during the upgrade.

I have been playing around performing minor upgrades with versions 1.6.20 and up and it seemes to me that the setup can handle it pretty well.

My Question is whether it is safe to perform a rolling upgrade. Having instances run with two different versions connected to the same database. So the upgrade process I'd like to have is:

```
step | intance1 | instance2 | instance3
0    | A        | A         | A
1    | B        | A         | A
2    | B        | B         | A
3    | B        | B         | B
```

Answer (score 1):

That link is actually to an older version of the 1.x documentation, here is the most recent 1.6 upgrade docs https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/upgrading/.

> NOTE:
>   When upgrading an HA setup, all rancher/server containers have to be stopped. The Rancher server setup will be down during the upgrade.

For 2.x the process is different since you are just upgrading the rancher helm chart.

Workloads will continue to run during this process though, so the interruption would just be to Rancher itself.